# : in Query Languages

Tags: sql, oracle

I am reading Joe Celko's *Trees and Hierarchies in SQL for Smarties* (2012) and have encountered SQL syntax with which I am unfamiliar:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Personnel_OrgChart 
WHERE path_string LIKE 
    (SELECT path_string 
     FROM Personnel_OrgChart 
     WHERE emp_id = :parent_emp_id) 
| | ‘%’;
```

The goal of the query is to select subordinates to a parent. The structure of the referenced table, `Personnel_OrgChart`, is:

```
+----------+--------+-------------+
| emp_name | emp_id | path_string |
+----------+--------+-------------+
| Bonnie   | A      | A           |
+----------+--------+-------------+
```

For full context, the explanation, quoted is:

> The subquery will use the indexing on the emp_id column to find the
>   “front part” of the path string from the root to the parent with whom
>   we are concerned. (p. 37).

What is the `:` and is that related to the not-found-in-table `parent_emp_id`? Where does the `parent_emp_id` come from?

Comment: I believe that it's just a placeholder to show where you would put the parent ID - whether through `JOIN`ing as part of a larger query or from a variable, etc.

Comment: Host variable `parent_emp_id`. (LIKE (sub-query) is a bit dangerous... I'd do a JOIN with LIKE instead.)

Comment: @jarlh what is a "host" variable?

Comment: If you write embedded SQL, it's a C or Cobol or Fortran varaible. (It can also be a named parameter. I.e. similar to `?`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean Oracle, it's a `bind variable`, you can read more about it in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96584/oci05bnd.htm#436227). Basically it's just a placeholder for input variables.

For example, given the `INSERT`statement

```
INSERT INTO emp VALUES
    (:empno, :ename, :job, :sal, :deptno)
```

and the following variable declarations

```
text     *ename, *job;
sword    empno, sal, deptno;
```

Comment: That looks to be what is implied by the query. Thank you. That's pulling up stuff from way back when I did SQL in school. As a developer, I don't often use inputs.

Comment: "I don't often use inputs" Then how do you do parameterized selects?  How do you pass values to updates and inserts?

Comment: @DStanley good point. A lot of that is done with scripted querying like LINQ, etc., ref. jarlh's comment regarding `?`. I am familiar with inputs. I meant having not directly worked with them in SQL in a long time.

Comment: @Thomas Gotcha - just making sure you weren't using string concatenation.

Answer (score 3):

This is a host variable

Example with COBOL on DB2

```
MOVE '000110' TO EMPID. 
EXEC SQL 
    SELECT LASTNAME 
    INTO :PGM-LASTNAME 
    FROM CORPDATA.EMPLOYEE 
    WHERE EMPNO = :EMPID 
END-EXEC.
DISPLAY "Employee name is " PGM-LASTNAME
```

Official doc : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_refs2hostvars.dita